# Celery- Disabling signals

Tags: python-3.x, celery, celery-task

I have used celery signals it is working fine

```
@shared_task(name="execute_task")
def execute(*args,**kwargs):
   return 2+2

@task_success.connect
def task_success_handler(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
   print(pass)
```

After the execute task is executed the task success signal is called, but I want to disable this call. Is it achievable?

Comment: I do not understand the question...

Comment: I have edited the question let me know if you couldn't get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes we can do this, celery signals also come with disconnect feature, so what you need to do is

```
from celery import signals
@shared_task(name="execute_task")
def execute(*args,**kwargs):
   signals.task_success.disconnect(task_success_handler)
   return 2+2
```

This way the success function won't be called.